# Grouping some fields in html form

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

In HTML form we can use class attributes to group some input fields (like: TextBox,DropDownList).

Example:

```
@Html.TextBox("MailingCity", null, new { @class = "block" })
@Html.DropDownList("MailingStateID", new SelectList(ViewBag.stateList, "value", "text"), new { @class = "block", @id = "ddlMailingStateList" })
```

After that we could work at script for all the fields by class.

Example:

```
$('.block').each(function () {

            var default_value = this.value;
            $(this).focus(function () {
                if (this.value == default_value) {
                    this.value = '';
                }
            });
            $(this).blur(function () {
                if (this.value == '') {
                    this.value = default_value;
                }
            });
        });
```

Is there any other possible way to group some field without *class*?
Actually, I want to write a common validate function at script section which will cover some input fields.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You can also select inputs by their position in the DOM.

Comment: With DOM combined (TextBox,DropDownList, datepicker, checkbox, etc) grouping possible?

Comment: What's wrong with class?
You can apply multiple classes to same html element.
According to the class you can specify different events to the html elements.

Comment: You can also use jQuery selectors.
Refer https://api.jquery.com/category/selectors/

Comment: @Metaphor hi Metaphor, will you be able to help on this Kendo issue https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61334924/kendo-grid-clienttemplate-if-else-condition

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, Finally I did it with html custom attribute.
Details:

At HTML:

```
@Html.TextBox("MiddleName", null, new { @class = "block", @myAtt="valid" })
```

At Script:

```
 $('[myatt="valid"]').each(function () {
            $(this).focus(function () {
                alert("Working...");
            });
            $(this).blur(function () {
                alert("Seriously?");
            });
        });
```

Here I use @myAtt="valid". And it's working well :)

Answer (score 0):

you can group fields by type selector.
for example:

`$('input[type=text]').each(function () {})`.

above line will give you all input fields having type equal to text. Similar logic you can apply to get all checkboxes, select boxes and so on.

for more example of jquery selector go to link [JQuery Selector](https://api.jquery.com/category/selectors/)

Comment: Thanks. But I need combined (TextBox,DropDownList, datepicker, checkbox, etc) grouping.

Answer (score 0):

in that case i will suggest to take a look at `jQuery(":input");`

this will give you all fields irrespective of text,select, button, textarea and so on. JQuery Documentation link [link](http://api.jquery.com/input-selector/)